# Can I push changes of one repository to another in Git?

Tags: git, github, bitbucket

I am working on a project currently and my employer has given me write access to the main repository of the project where he merged the repository in which I was working I think. A particular branch is specified to me.

Now he wishes I make some changes and push them to this repository. I have not worked with Git on large projects before. Is it possible to that I just make changes in the repository I am working in and keep pushing it to the main repository and Git will keep merging them? How does this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Git pushing doesn't merge anything; it just transmits objects to the remote repository and updates branch heads. It's basically a form of file synchronization with revision awareness.

All the editing takes place locally, and so it is with Git: you do all the commit preparation, merging and so on, in your local repo. Upstream repositories cannot even do most of this stuff because they are "bare": they do not have a working tree. If you were to log into the server and enter the upstream Git repository, you wouldn't be able to do any rebasing, or merging or anything of the sort.

I'm guessing that the boss has set up the master repository as a "remote" for your local repository. Take a peek inside the `.git/config` file.

If everything is set up correctly, you should be able to commit to this local branch and then do a push to make the upstream branch look like the local one.

If other people have pushed something to the branch before you, you can integrate their changes with `git pull --rebase`, fix any conflicts and try again. The merging is all done locally.

Your push will succeed when the new changes you are pushing are based on the same parent commit which matches the upstream branch head: i.e. there is nothing newer upstream than the baseline you are working against. In this case, your change is a "fast-forward change".

Git detects and blocks non-fast-forward changes (meaning that newer things exist on the branch in the upstream repository which would be clobbered if your version of the branch were pushed). So when your changes are ready for publication, there is no harm in trying `git push`.  When it doesn't work, you have to pull to integrate, and try again; the upstream doesn't do any integration.

Comment: I tried cloning into the repository for which I have been given write access. It took a couple of minutes to clone the whole thing. But when I finally opened, it just had a read me file and nothing else. Is this because I don't have read permissions or something?

Comment: @Rohan You mean "tried cloning the remote repository to create a local repository", right? A possible reason why you don't see anything is that you are not on the correct branch. You may have to do a `git checkout <some-branch>`. Perhaps the default `master` branch doesn't have anything other than the README file because your team does all the work on branches other than `master`. Do a `git branch -r` to view all the branches.

Comment: @Rohan Note that to get on the correct branch you don't have to pull any new material from the remote repo; the clone has pulled in all the objects. The branch checkout purely a local operation.

Comment: That makes so much sense now. I tried doing git branch to see the branches earlier and couldn't figure out what was going on. What is the -r option for? And yes, I can see the work now. Lovely.

Comment: @Rohan The `-r` option shows you the remote tracking branches. Without that you see local branches and with `-a` you see all of them.  When you check out a remote branch, a local one is created for it and you're actually on that local one. The pair of them is used by git to figure out what is going on: which one has new changes relative to the other, or are they diverged.

Comment: So now when I make changes to my specified_branch, I will do a git push origin specified_branch, right?

Comment: @Rohan You shouldn't have to do the `origin specified_branch` part, because the branch automatically has tracking info connecting it to the remote tracking branch. Just `git push`.   By the way, why `git branch` doesn't show the remote branches is ... that in some situations, the list can be huge. It would be annoying when people just want to see the branches they care about: the ones they checked out and and have locally.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do but you really need an understanding of how Git and distributed version controls work. There are several common workflows used with Git and you should check with your employer to see how they use it. Here is a basic tutorial: https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/